# Disable button for user login in WinForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

In my WinForms application, I have 3 forms,

1. Login form
2. Main form
3. Data entry form

When the login is "User", the Main form should open. But in the childform "data entry" - "button1" should be disabled.

When the login is **"Admin"**, the Main form should open. But in the childform "data entry" - "button1" should be enabled.

I have tried with the below code, but the button1 is working no matter who is logged on.

Kindly guide me on how to achieve this:

```
private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cmbusername.Text != "" && txtpassword.Text != "")
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        string query = "select * from login where username = @user and password = @pass";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", cmbusername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtpassword.Text);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows == true)
        {
            if(cmbusername.Text == "USER")
            {
                FormDataEntry frmd = new FormDataEntry();
                frmd.button1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if(cmbusername.Text == "ADMIN")
            {
                FormDataEntry frmd = new FormDataEntry();
                frmd.button1.Enabled = true;
            }
            this.Hide();
            FrmMain FrmMain = new FrmMain();
            FrmMain.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
        }

        con.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in both fields");
    }
    
}
```

Pics of my app in sequence

1. First login form will open
2. Next dashboard(formMain) will open for both of the "User" & "Admin"
3. Next when the "initial data entry" is clicked on the left side menu, a child form (formdataentry) will open, in this I need to disable the delete button if the login is as a user.

[image: This is my login form]

[image: This is my dashboard from which opens after login]

[image: In this form I want the delete button to be disabled]

Comment: you make a new instance of FormDataEntry but you will never show this form. if you call frmd.Show(), your form will be opened and button will be disabled, right ?

Comment: The conditions … _”when the login is "User" , Main form should open , but in the childform "data entry" - "button1" should be disabled. when the login is "User" , Main form should open , but in the childform "data entry" - "button1" should be enabled.”_ … ? … These conditions are contradictory. If the login is “User”, then the “data entry” “button1” can not be BOTH enabled and disabled. You should edit this and clarify what you mean. From the code, I assume the second login should be ”Admin” to enable the button.

Comment: It is strange to instantiate the `FormDataEntry` form for both the “User” and the “Admin.” If the `FormDataEntry` is not available to the “User,” they why instantiate it in the first place? It would appear that the `button1` you are trying to enable/disable should be on the `FrmMain` form and NOT the `FormDataEntry` form. This is speculation without more info.

Comment: so sorry ..it's not user on the second line it's ADmin

Comment: Set admin rights to user, check if the user not met the user rights then set button1.visible = false.

Comment: hi @senthilkumar2185 ..i didn't understand could you explain further? Or through code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class FormDataentry: Form
{
    public static bool _userrights = false;

    private void FormDataentry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_userrights==false)
        {
            btnDelete.Visible =false;
        }
    }
}

//frmlogin
private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cmbusername.Text == "USER")
    {
        FormDataEntry._userrights=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need this line: `FormDataEntry frmd = new FormDataEntry();`...just use `FormDataEntry._userrights=false;`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that will hold the type of user that is logged in:

```
public class User
{
    public enum enumUserType
    {
        USER,
        ADMIN
    }
    public static enumUserType UserType = enumUserType.USER;
}
```

Then, in your `btnlogin_Click()` method, you can set that value:

```
if(cmbusername.Text == "USER")
{
    User.UserType = User.enumUserType.USER;            
}
else if(cmbusername.Text == "ADMIN")
{
    User.UserType = User.enumUserType.ADMIN;
}
```

Finally in the `Load()` event of your "Data entry form", you can set the state of the button:

```
public partial class FormDataEntry : Form
{
    public FormDataEntry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FormDataEntry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = (User.UserType == User.enumUserType.ADMIN);
    }
}
```

You'll be able to use `User.UserType` from anywhere in your application, possibly in other forms/areas that need to know the type of the user logged in.